# Issues with serialization of pipeline json from Azure SDK for python

Tags: azure-sdk-python

I'm trying to extract the JSON for pipelines in a certain resource group. The issue I'm running into is when I look at the JSON given by the code below (specifically the JSON for the activities in the pipeline), it is different to the JSON on Azure for that pipeline.

```
pipelines = DataFactoryManagementClient(cred, sub_id).pipelines.list_by_factory(fac_resource_group_name, fac_name)
        for pipeline in pipelines:
            print(pipeline.serialize()["properties"]["activities"])
```

Outputs:

```
{
    'name': 'geomoby data flow', 
    'type': 'ExecuteDataFlow', 
    'dependsOn': [], 
    'userProperties': [], 
    'policy': {
        'timeout': '1.00:00:00',
        'retry': 0,
        'retryIntervalInSeconds': 30,
        'secureInput': False,
        'secureOutput': False
    }, 
    'typeProperties': {
        'staging': {}, 
        'integrationRuntime': {
            'type': 'IntegrationRuntimeReference', 
            'referenceName': 'integrationRuntime1'
        }, 
        'traceLevel': 'None'
    }   
}
```

But online, that same activity is:

```
{
    "name": "geomoby data flow",
    "type": "ExecuteDataFlow",
    "dependsOn": [],
    "policy": {
        "timeout": "1.00:00:00",
        "retry": 0,
        "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
        "secureOutput": false,
        "secureInput": false
    },
    "userProperties": [],
    "typeProperties": {
        "dataflow": {
            "referenceName": "geomoby_data_flow",
            "type": "DataFlowReference",
            "parameters": {
                "filename_data_flow": {
                    "value": "'@{pipeline().parameters.geomobdataflow_filename}'",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        },
        "integrationRuntime": {
            "referenceName": "integrationRuntime1",
            "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
        },
        "traceLevel": "None",
        "cacheSinks": {
            "firstRowOnly": true
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is extract the the "dataflow" and its constituents from "typeProperties"

EDIT: Fixed the json formatting.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to get the JSON of a pipeline that has a data flow activity using the code below:

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.datafactory import DataFactoryManagementClient
import json

client = DataFactoryManagementClient(
    credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
    subscription_id="<subscriptionId>"
)

response = client.pipelines.get(
    resource_group_name="<resourceGroupName>",
    factory_name="<ADFName>",
    pipeline_name='<pipeline>'
)

# Convert the response to JSON
pipeline_json = response.serialize()

# Print the JSON representation of the pipeline
print(json.dumps(pipeline_json, indent=4))
```

I got the JSON as shown below:

[image]

It is in the same format that you got, but when I tried with the execute pipeline activity, I was able to get the type properties as mentioned below:

[image]

It is working for all activities, but it is not working only for the data flow activity. This might be a bug.

Comment: I think so too, for all the other activities this issue does not arise, I've only managed to find it for dataflows.